# how to use multiple components in AppRegistry in react-native

Tags: react-native

I would like to have more information about the AppRegistry using multiple components. Is there any example with this?
Does each one of them have their on javascript environment? What happens when you unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag? is the javascript environment nuked as well?

Comment: very implortant question.. there is no documentation about AppRegistry anywhere on the internet,
i hope one of react-native developers helps out here

Comment: did you find any solution ?